# Recover full command that generated core dump

Tags: rhel, core-dump

A program I am working on is crashing and generating core dumps. I think that the issue is related to the arguments that it's being called with, some of which are automatically generated by another (rather complicated) program. So I've tried using `gdb` to debug, or `file core.MyApplication.1234` to get the arguments.

However, the command is pretty lengthy, and the output looks something like:

```
core.MyApplication.1234: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from './MyApplication -view -mwip localhost -mwnp 12345 -mwlp 12346 -mwti 12347 -Debu'
```

(I did change the names for this example, but you get the idea.)

I know for a fact that there were several more arguments after this, but in the core files the command is always truncated at 80 characters. Both `gdb` and `file` report this. Looking at the output of `objdump` I'm not sure the rest was even written into the core dump, because it appears to cut off after "-Debu" too.

I am running this on RHEL6. I found [this thread from 2007](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.solaris/length-of-command-line-as-recorded-in-a-cor/366923) describing a solution for Solaris systems using `pargs`, but that's not a valid command on my system, and the Red Hat "equivalents" I've found only work on running processes, not a core file.

How can I recover the entire command used to run the program? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is there (at least up to 999 entries totalling at least 6885 bytes of numbered blahs):

```
> cat segfault.c 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *s = "hello world";
    *s = 'H';
}
> cc -g -o segfault segfault.c
> limit coredumpsize 9999999
> ./segfault `perl -le 'print "blah$_" for 1..999'`
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> strings core.12231 | grep -c blah
1000
```

Then with some quick altagoobingleduckgoing of `gdb`, and assuming debug symbols, this can be recovered via something like:

```
> gdb ./segfault core.12231
...
(gdb) p argc
$1 = 1000
(gdb) x/1000s *argv
...
```

Another option would be to use a simple shell wrapper that logs `"$@"` somewhere then `exec`s the proper program with the given arguments.

Comment: I don't know why that didn't occur to me earlier, but thanks for the quick response and example :)

Comment: `strings -n100 coredumpfile` :P

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [`pargs` version for Linux](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility#pargs). Thus, given the core file, you can display all arguments with it under RHEL 6, as well:

```
$ pargs core.MyApplication.1234
argv[0]: /usr/libexec/gvfsd-network
argv[1]: --spawner
argv[2]: :1.16
argv[3]: /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2
```

Alternatively, if you have `gdb` and the executable still available you can display all arguments with GDB:

```
$ gdb MyApplication core.MyApplication.1234
(gdb) bt
[..]
#4  0x000055a376101e1b in main (argc=4, argv=0x7ffca4780f08)
                       at daemon-main-generic.c:45
(gdb) frame 4
(gdb) set print address off
(gdb) show print pretty
(gdb) p *argv@argc
$1 = {"/usr/libexec/gvfsd-network", "--spawner", ":1.16",
      "/org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2"}
```

Comparing the two approaches, `pargs` just requires a core file and doesn't need further interactive input.